# Can I periodically recalculate an attribute after a given time interval?

Tags: ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-4, model, attributes

I have a model "User", with a float attribute "Value". I want each User's Value to depreciate 1%(i.e., be multiplied by 0.99) every 24 hours after the User's creation. For example, if a User is created with a Value of 5 at 02:34 on January 1st, then at 02:34 on January 2nd, its value should be recalculated to be 4.95. Then at 02:34 on January 3rd, it should be recalculated to be 4.9005, and so on.

Can this be done?

I'm using a Rails 4.0.10 app, if that matters.

Comment: consider using delayed jobs https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job

Comment: How important is it that the value changes exactly after 24 hours, is it aproblem when it happens a hour later? Do you need that updated value stored in the database, or is it enough when the value is calculated at the moment someone reads it?

Comment: @spickermann I just want every user to depreciate at the same constant rate. So if it takes a little over or under a day that doesn't really matter, as long as it's the same for every user, and it's always the same interval. Yes, the updated value should be stored in the database.

Comment: you could set a delayed job to fire in the frequency you mentioned. Shouldn't that work ?

Comment: @PamioSolanky What is a delayed job? Are you referring to the gem shivam mentioned?

Comment: Yes. You could set up a delayed job (rails specific) . You could always go for cron jobs which is a good option too

Comment: @PamioSolanky I see, thanks. I was hoping I wouldn't have to install anything but I guess I'll give delayed jobs a shot.

Comment: If value can be calculated when you want to display/read it, then I'd suggest that you do the calculation in code rather than updating it in db periodically. But, if you must update the value then you'd need a cron job, delayed job is for scheduling the jobs at a particular time, delayed jobs don't run periodically, for that you need cron jobs. Probably a gem like [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) would be good fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) gem you could do something like this:

```
# in user.rb
after_create :decrease_value_periodically

private
def decrease_value_periodically
  self.value = value * 0.99
  self.save!

  decrease_value_periodically if value > 0
end
handle_asynchronously :decrease_value_periodically, 
                      :run_at => Proc.new { 24.hours.from_now }
```

This example would run 24 hours after creation of an user and would reschedule itself over and over again.

---

Another option might be a daily Cron task that recalculates all user's values at the same time (midnight for example). You could setup a Cron task that runs a Rails method like this:

```
# command for Cron
rails runner "User.recalculate_all_values"

# in user.rb
def self.recalculate_all_values
  User.all.each { |user| user.decrease_value }
end

private
def decrease_value
  if value > 0
    self.value = value * 0.99
    self.save!
  end
end
```

IMO it depends on your priorities: If you want a precise run after 24 hours, choose delayed_jobs. Whereas the Cron solution is easier to maintain, but you might end up with decreasing values to early or to late (Imagine a user is created at 11pm and one hour later the Cron task starts to decrase the value for the first time).

Comment: delayed job is for scheduling jobs, not for running periodical jobs, for example, running every hour, day, or month. In that case delayed job will be a very bad suggestion IMO.

Comment: I think delayed_jobs are a good solution here, because what ElGuapo needs is not a periodical job (at a fixed time every day). He needs scheduled jobs (24 hours after creation of each individual user). And that is what delayed_jobs offers.

Comment: Not really, OP suggests that on 2nd Jan(day after the user is created), value should be decreased by 1% which is 4.95, and again on 3rd by 1% which is 4.9005, and so on. This solution will schedule one job for next day, it won't be scheduling it for everyday.

Comment: It seems like delayed_jobs would be the better choice in my case, because I need the job to be periodically run after a given interval after creation, not at a given time every day. Spickerman, delayed_jobs would in fact save each update to the database, and then use that saved value for the next update, right?

Comment: @Surya: I fixed the rate to decrease. About the scheduling: It will reschedule every day while the value is `>0`, because it calls `decrease_value_periodically` recursively...

Comment: @ElGuapo : Yes.. delayed job will run that code once, i.e. for the next day(24 hours), not every day.

Comment: @ElGuapo: My example would `save!` the updated `value` on every run. And it reschedules itself for the next day. Cron is not an option, because it does not have the flexibility when to run.

Comment: @spickermann : I see, now it makes sense. But, don't you think that server will be bombarded with delayed jobs for each user, if db has 1000 users, there will be 1000 delayed jobs. Will increase per user for every entry.

Comment: @Surya I thought that was actually an advantage. Would cron jobs only have to run one job every day no matter the db size? My worry with cron jobs was that it would run 1000(or however many) jobs at a specific time once a day, and the server would be overloaded at that particular time, so it would be better to spread out the calculations.

Comment: @spickermann Thank you for your excellent answer. It seems that Cron would be easier on the server.