# Best time/duration gem for rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time

I'd like to start a new project using time-based attributes, but I want to be sure about the best method to do so. Basically, I'm facing two major questions (to simplify, let's use a RPG-ish vocabulary)

First of all, each user has a `gold_coins` integer attribute. I'd like to increase this amount periodically. At first, I thought of using delayed jobs, but browsing over SO, it seems like it's a bad thing to do, as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27619280/can-i-periodically-recalculate-an-attribute-after-a-given-time-interval)

Second, user can produce units. Each `unit` takes a certain amount of time to be produced, defined by its `production_time` attribute. So far, I thought of creating a `Production` model, creating a new one everytime a unit is produced. Production has a `start_datetime`, and an `end_datetime` calculated using the unit `production time`. My question is, how can I keep track of elapsed time, so that when the production ends, it starts the matching job (once again, delayed jobs seemed to fit perfectly, but it seems like they're not particularly appreciated amongst developers).

Answer (score 0):

Not with delayed job, but I will suggest to rely on OS level time/interval mechanism for this, for example CRON jobs, OS-specific scheduling engines etc.

You can easily write a rake task with your business logic, and call this task from within the CRON. This will make your overall logic decoupled at a good level.

Also, system-level scheduling engines are easier to configure and maintain.